# Pass a PHP variable in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, elgg

I know this is a frequent question but my case is different. Here is My code

PHP

```
if($mode == "All" || $mode == 'Offline')
        {
                echo "<label>By categories :</label>";
                echo elgg_view('input/pulldown',array(
                        'options' => $options_values,
                        'internalname' => 'event_type',
                        'value' => get_input('event_type'),
                        'js' => 'onchange = set_filter('. $mode .')','internalid' => 'event_cat'

                ));
        }
```

In same file i have written the script

Java script

```
function set_filter(mode){

    var url = $('#event_cat option:selected').val();
    alert(mode);    
    if ( mode == "Offline"){
    var off_url = <?php $vars['url'] ?>"pg/event_calendar/filter/?&amp;callback=true&event_type={url}&mode=offline";
    alert(off_url);
    }

}
```

The problem i am facing is i want to pass the **"$mode"** variable in **"'js' => 'onchange = set_filter('. $mode .')'"** function as a argument. But it saying undefined as alert in script. How to pass the variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` your php variable:

```
var off_url = "<?php echo $vars['url']; ?>pg/event etc...";
```

As is, your code is simply a different version of

```
<?php
true;
```

which does nothing at all except suck up a bit of cpu time.

As well, be **EXTREMELY** careful when directly dumping data from PHP into a javascript context. If you have ANY javascript metacharacters in the output data, you risk introducing a syntax error. In general, you should always `json_encode()` anything PHP is outputting, but this also depends on HOW you're inserting the PHP data into the JS code block.

Comment: I want to pass the variable $mode in php in condition. See the onchange function. I need to pass the variable as a argument.

Comment: You have to remember that you're generating javascript code. Whatever PHP outputs has to be valid when the JS engine comes across it. `some_js_func(<?php echo 'foo' ?>)` is going to generate `some_js_func(foo)`... unless you've got a variable named `foo` in that scope, this code will fail with undefined variable. `some_js_func('<?php echo 'foo' ?>');` (note the extra `'` quotes...) would work: `some_js_func('foo')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var off_url = "<?php $vars['url'] ?>pg/event_calendar/filter/?&amp;callback=true&event_type={url}&mode=offline";
```

And in your js pass will be like

```
'js' => 'onchange = set_filter("'. $mode .'")'
```

Comment: I want to pass the variable $mode in php in condition. See the onchange function. I need to pass the variable as a argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'js' => 'onchange = set_filter("'. $mode .'")'
```

Comment: NO buddy i tried like this but not working..

Comment: did you check the value of parameter passed to set_filter when its called using firebug?

Comment: yes buddy that's not working. I checked it..

Comment: did it has value of the $mode you passed ? if yes then is it in double quotes or unquoted?

Comment: It is showing set_filetr('..')

Comment: then you are updating the value of mode before using onchange = set_filter(....) on the pulldown file because I tested it in CodeIgniter way and its working fine.